# Configuring iPad Mail app & Gmail app with different accounts?

Tags: email, gmail, sharing, ipad

I prefer to use the Gmail app over the standard Mail app on my iPad for reading my personal Gmail (I delete a lot of mails, newsletters, etc., after reading and this is one tap in Gmail and several in Mail).

I have them set up so my personal Gmail uses the Gmail app and my work email is set up to use the standard Mail app. This all works fine except for one problem. If I'm in Gmail or Mail and send an email it sends from the relevant email address as expected. My problem is that when I share something via email from Safari or another app it sends from the email address configured in Settings for Mail (the work one) and I would prefer to do such sharing from my personal email address.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve this? I could switch the addresses to use the other app but as I never delete work email and delete personal mail at least 50% of the time, the behaviour of the apps is perfect the way I have them set up; if only I could solve that one little problem of controlling where shared items are sent from.

I am using an iPad 2 with iOS 5.1 should that be relevant.

Comment: I'm 95% sure that, like web browsers, it's not possible to open mailto: links or built-in shares in a third-party app on iOS. Unless you're jailbroken?

Comment: I fear you may be right. Unfortunately the iPad Gmail app can't quickly switch between accounts (we use Google mail at work) like my Android phone or the Gmail web client can. If it could I would just set the standard mail app to use my personal address and ignore it for reading and sending mail; it would just handle sending shared items in the background.

Comment: And why can't you just set up both accounts in Mail?

Comment: Didn't see your comment until after posting my answer. That's exactly what I've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a way to do this that will work for me.

I already had my Gmail account added in Mail, calendar & contacts settings but with mail turned off. Once I turned mail on and did a test of sharing a page from Safari, I noticed that I now had access to the From header; the default was my work address but I could change it to my personal one. Checked settings again and found a Default Account setting; changed it to my personal account and now it's using that as the default for sharing via email. I can still use the Gmail app to work with my personal mail, while the Mail app has access to both accounts.

Answer (score 0):

In your desktop Gmail you can, in Settings, add other accounts that you can use for "sending.". Then, when on my iPad (new), I can tap in the From box and access my other account as "sender." as far as I know you must set this up in the desktop/web version of Gmail.